# How can I use `class` as Map's key?

Tags: dart

I use `Piece class` as Map's key.

But when this code ran,  error occured `Uncaught exception:
C.JSNull_methods.$indexSet is not a function`.

```dart
class Piece {
  int type;

  Piece(this.type);
}

void main() {
  Map<Piece, int> hand;
  hand[Piece(5)] = 5;

  if (hand.containsKey(Piece(5))) {
    print("contains");
  }

  print('${hand[Piece(5)]}');
}
```

In dart-lang, how can I use `class` as Map's key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the error you got has nothing to do with using types as keys but are before you never initialize the hand variable. So you need to do this:

```
Map<Piece, int> hand = {};
```

Now, you will not get the exception but your code will properly not work as expected since `hand.containsKey(Piece(5))` will return false and `print('${hand[Piece(5)]}')` will return `null`.

This is because the map `Map<Piece, int>` are not using the Type as key but instead objects of the type `Piece`. So if we take your code here:

```
  Map<Piece, int> hand = {};
  hand[Piece(5)] = 5;

  if (hand.containsKey(Piece(5))) {
    print("contains");
  }

  print('${hand[Piece(5)]}');
```

You are here creating a new object instance of the Piece type each type you are writing "Piece(5)". Since each of this objects will be a separate instance of a Piece then you will not receive the value 5 you have saved because the value 5 has been saved for a different object than you are requesting.

There are multiple solutions for that and I don't know which one are the best for you. But the simple solution in this case is to either only creating one instance of Piece and reuse that:

```
void main() {
  Map<Piece, int> hand = {};
  final piece = Piece(5);
  hand[piece] = 5;

  if (hand.containsKey(piece)) {
    print("contains");
  }

  print('${hand[piece]}');
}
```

Or make a const constructor for your Piece class so instances with the same arguments are made into the same object. This solution requires that the `int type` are final since you cannot edit a const constructed object (since it is constant):

```
class Piece {
  final int type;

  const Piece(this.type);
}

void main() {
  Map<Piece, int> hand = {};
  hand[const Piece(5)] = 5;

  if (hand.containsKey(const Piece(5))) {
    print("contains");
  }

  print('${hand[const Piece(5)]}');
}
```

Note that you need to prefix you object instantiation with `const` like "const Piece(5)" each time you want a instance where you are sure it will returns the same object for the same arguments.